# Modify the value in settings bundle in iphone

Tags: iphone, settings, bundle

I need to modify the value of the key in the settings bundle through code whenever i get the new value for that key.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.
You apps bundles are all read-only.

Comment: Longer answer: Your app bundles are read-only because they are signed, changing their content would break the signing and the app would be considered to be tampered with and not run.

Comment: Is it possible to copy all the settings of my setting bundle in to some other plist file and move that file to documents directory and work on it?

Comment: Sure, you have write access to the documents folder